Laravel Vapor gives error : - The variables may not be greater than 2000 characters
I downloaded the env file from staging env using vapor env:pull staging and I updated it with my local env variables and then I run vapor env:push and then it gives me an error like:

The variables may not be greater than 2000 characters.

Then i go to the document https://docs.vapor.build/projects/environments.html#:~:text=To%20accommodate%20Vapor's%20own%20injection,if%20you%20exceed%20this%20limit
where they are saying to encrypt and use it. I encrypted and then trying to upload it again but it gives me the same error.
How to resolve this?
